# PivotTable Report Action Url limit of 1024

Tags: excel, url, report, ssas, pivot-table

I am trying to create an action in excel pivot report which goes to a specified URL with multiple parameters appended to the URL. This action is implemented in the ssas cube. But I came to know that max URL length limit is 1024 characters. So is there a work around this?

Comment: I don't believe the code already exists so I won't post this as an answer. But I suppose you could use a .NET sproc running in SSAS to build the URL. It could capture the current filter context and write that to a database and assign a GUID then build a URL with that GUID. Then the web page could lookup the GUID in the database to retrieve the filter context and return the right report. Quite a bit of effort but would certainly work.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for the suggestion. I can build the URL using SSAS actions features. The issue I am facing here is with the length of the URL. When I try to access the ssrs report with the built URL through excel actions , the length of the URL might go beyond the 1024 character limit. So is there a way to access the web page with URL length not being a limitation?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean is to have a .NET sproc build a shortened URL. Then the webpage can lookup the longer filter context in a database.